# Android date picker style

Tags: android

[image: Date picker screenshot]

I need to change the color of the date picker in android from gray color to green is this possible?

Comment: I think you can use this tutorial : http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.fr/2013/03/how-to-create-custom-date-time-picker.html

Comment: Have you looked into this at all? What have you tried so far? Any related code to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upto my knowledge. You can't able to change the color of the default datepicker.It's color and theme varies depends device manufaturer.If you want to change the color you have to create custom datepicker.